# Rails simple validations not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name
  validates :name,:presence=>true,
                                :length=>{:maximum=>15}
    validates :email,:presence=>true,
                                :length=>{:maximum=>15}

end
```

I am new to rails and the simplest of the validators are not working. I think I may be making a very silly mistake . I have a User model with 2 attributes only and when I create a new user in ruby console with wrong validations like no name or a longer name than 15 characters it gets added happily Please suggest.I am using rails version:3.2.13 and ruby version:1.9.3

Comment: Did you restart Rails server or console after adding the validations? Are you sure the record was actually added to the database? (Does `User.all` list the record you added?)

Comment: If you say `:presence => false` for email, why dont you delete the column itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on rails console, be sure to type `reload!` after making changes to models. In this way, all changes will be reloaded in the console instance.

Moreover, are you sure you are saving these models? You should try something like this:

```
user = User.new(email: "john.doe@gmail.com")
user.save
```

If the result of the last line is `false`, you can view the validation errors with

```
p user.errors
```